# using bonjour on ios4 for wifi

Tags: networking, ios4, bonjour

Before getting into all the technicalities about Bonjour. I want to know whether Bonjour is meant for Wifi.

I need to do a simple app, that talks to a Wifi router, connects to a device,and sends some very small information and receives very small information. I have seen a lot of examples that use CFNetworking and things seem unnecessarily crowded for a newbie.

Is there a concrete link explaining what Bonjour is all about OR the other way round: Whats the best thing to do to use wifi? Any references would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour is primarily designed to function over a link-local network; it doesn't matter whether clients are using a wired or wireless connection.

If you need to be concerned with finding the router then Zero-conf networking may not be what you want. If all you need to do is find a device somewhere on the network then it may well suit your needs.

If you want to understand more about Bonjour I suggest you consult the [Multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org/) page for more information.

If you're developing on a Mac / iPhone and just want to dive in, you will typically use the [NSNetService](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and NSNetServiceBrowser classes. Check out Apple's [Bonjour Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000119i) as well.

Comment: Chris, this helps, thanks! Right now, I only need to find a device on the network. But later on, I might try to talk to a router. To cover my question totally, any links/references/suggestions to talk to a wifi router.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'talk to'- do you need to set up port mappings/ something else?

Comment: Not really, I do have the machine address and the port number to which I must send messages (talk to). All I need to do is to send and receive some data from this machine.